# Build an lambda Expression tree with a specific field in a linked entity

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

Data MODEL

```
public class TABLE
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ONEFIELD { get; set; }

        // -------------------- ForeignKey --------------------
        [ForeignKey("People")]
        public long PeopleID { get; set; }
        public virtual People People { get; set; }
    }

    public class People
    {
        [Key]
        public long PeopleID { get; set; }
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to build a lambda to query this MODEL :

> Get TABLE.ONEFIELD = 1 AND TABLE.PEOPLE.COUNTRYID = 6

LINQ equivalent

```
_context.TABLEs
  .Where(e => e.ONEFIELD == 1)
  .Include(e => e.People)
  .Where(i=>i.People.CountryID == 6);
```

My try

```
  public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildLambda<TEntity>(OBJTYPE obj)
        {

        var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "table");
        Expression query = null;


        // 1
        var prop1 = Expression.Property(item, "ONEFIELD");
        var value1 = Expression.Constant(1);
        var equal1 = Expression.Equal(prop1, value1);
        var lambdaFIELDONE = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equal1, item);
        query = lambdaFIELDONE.Body;

        // 2
        var prop2 = Expression.Property(item, typeof(People).Name + ".CountryID");
        var value2 = Expression.Constant(6);
        var equal2 = Expression.Equal(prop2, value2);
        var lambdaCOUNTRYID = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equal2, item);
        query = Expression.And(query, lambdaCOUNTRYID);

    }
```

but I receive this error

> System.ArgumentException: Instance property 'People.CountryID' is not defined for type 'SOLUTION.Models.TABLE'

I don't need Generic, just a fixed lambda (and I couldn't use LINQ).

I tried several things to catch People.CountryID like

```
Expression.Property(item1, typeof(People).GetProperty("CountryID"));
Expression.Property(item, typeof(People).Name+"." + typeof(People).GetProperty("CountryID"));
Expression.Property(item, typeof(People).Name + "." + typeof(People).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == "CountryID").FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

no success

Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: You need to nest two `Expression.Property` expressions to represent each step in the access. I recommend getting LINQPad and using the `Dump` method: you can create an `LambdaExpression<Func<>>` variable and dump it to see how it was built.

Comment: Also you have a number of errors: 1. No reason to create `lambdaFIELDONE` only to immediately take it apart to get `Body` - `equal1` __is__ the body. 2. You can put a lambda in `Expression.And` (consider: q = q && (x => z)) - it makes no sense. You create the lambda last after the body is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to build a nested property access, you must nest the `Expression`s that access each level. Then you can combine the tests into a body and finally create the lambda for the result:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildLambda<TEntity>(OBJTYPE obj) {
    // (TEntity table)
    var parmTable = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "table");

    // table.ONEFIELD
    var prop1 = Expression.Property(parmTable, "ONEFIELD");
    // table.ONEFIELD == 1
    var equal1 = Expression.Equal(prop1, Expression.Constant(1));

    // table.People
    var prop2_1 = Expression.Property(parmTable, nameof(People));
    // table.People.CountryID
    var prop2_2 = Expression.Property(prop2_1, "CountryID");
    // table.People.CountryID == 6
    var equal2 = Expression.Equal(prop2_2, Expression.Constant(6));

    // table.ONEFIELD == 1 && table.People.CountryID == 6
    var finalBody = Expression.AndAlso(equal1, equal2);

    // table => table.ONEFIELD == 1 && table.People.CountryID == 6
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(finalBody, parmTable);
}
```

Using LINQPad, you could create a sample lambda and then use the `Dump` method and you would see that a nested `FieldExpression` is created, which is what gets created when you call `Expression.Property`:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> f = t => t.People.CountryID;

f.Dump();
```

Comment: and that works ! thank you so much.
You have improved my understanding of "Expression.Property", but I still have efforts to do to better master the "Expression".
Thanks for the advice on LINQPAD, I will try.